# Pandas to_csv Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to export a df to csv where I have already specified 3 columns as dfs but when exporting to csv, pandas creates a new column with index or no index is imported at all. Have already tried following code:

```
merge_df.set_index(['Id','Part Id','Order Id'])
merge_df.to_csv('/Downloads/Dataframe.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?

Comment: The mistake everybody mistakes - you are not keeping the new index at all. You need `merge_df = merge_df.set_index(['Id','Part Id','Order Id'])` or `merge_df.set_index(['Id','Part Id','Order Id'], inplace=True)`